# Retrieve several items from a list by ids

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array such as :

```
const cars = [
  { id: 23423, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23452, brand: 'volvo', doors: 4, color: 'gray' },
  { id: 97456, brand: 'citroen', doors: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 45784, brand: 'dodge', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23452, brand: 'ferrari', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23522, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'blue' }
];
```

Here i have a list of ids such as : `[45784, 23522]`

I'd like to find the best way using map, filter or reduce to retrieve the items in the first array using the ids array.

Thanks

Comment: how do you define "best way"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could filter by using [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

This proposal uses a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for the `id` property of the object.

```js
var cars = [{ id: 23423, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'red' }, { id: 23452, brand: 'volvo', doors: 4, color: 'gray' }, { id: 97456, brand: 'citroen', doors: 4, color: 'black' }, { id: 45784, brand: 'dodge', doors: 2, color: 'red' }, { id: 23452, brand: 'ferrari', doors: 2, color: 'red' }, { id: 23522, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'blue' }],
    ids = [45784, 23522],
    result = cars.filter(({ id }) => ids.includes(id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I thought i would need an approach based on a reducer. I might not understand well in which case i can take the best out of it.

Comment: a reduce is for anything, but filter is more specion by returning only some items from the array. reduce is good for a single loop, if necessary and filter not oly some parts, but change the returned result.

Answer (score 8):

Simple as:

```js
const 
  cars = [
  { id: 23423, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23452, brand: 'volvo', doors: 4, color: 'gray' },
  { id: 97456, brand: 'citroen', doors: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 45784, brand: 'dodge', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23452, brand: 'ferrari', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23522, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'blue' }
],
  ids = [45784, 23522];

let arr = cars.filter(elem => ids.includes(elem.id));

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) from the `ids` array, and use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to take only items that exist in the Set:

```js
const cars = [
  { id: 23423, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23452, brand: 'volvo', doors: 4, color: 'gray' },
  { id: 97456, brand: 'citroen', doors: 4, color: 'black' },
  { id: 45784, brand: 'dodge', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23452, brand: 'ferrari', doors: 2, color: 'red' },
  { id: 23522, brand: 'bmw', doors: 2, color: 'blue' }
];

const ids = [45784, 23522];

const idsSet = new Set(ids);
const result = cars.filter(({ id }) => idsSet.has(id));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: instead of converting to a set, you could just use `array.includes`

Comment: Why did you use a Set? To stop duplicates?

Comment: Set.has is faster than array.includes - https://www.aaronm.net/javascript-speedtest-array-indexof-vs-array-includes-vs-set-has/